# Hibernate case-insensitive utf-8/unicode collation that works on multiple DBMS

Tags: database, string, hibernate, collation, string-matching

I'm looking for Hibernate annotation or .hbm.xml that allows me to specify a table column as case-insensitive string working in unicode/utf-8/locale-independent manner that works on multiple database engines.

Is there any such thing?

So that I can do query using `Restrictions.eq("column_name", "search_string")` efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no mapping or annotation like that. Your options are:

1. Handle this by specifying appropriate collation at the database level.
2. Use [lower()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) function that's defined for majority of (all?) dialects.
3. If you want to use Criteria only, use `Restrictions.ilike()` for case-insensitive comparison. It actually uses `lower()` internally.